# Warnings in `.SD` when selecting columns named in a variable

Tags: r, data.table

Assuming I have a `data.table` as below

```
DT <- data.table(x = rep(c("b", "a", "c"), each = 3), v = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2), y = c(1, 3, 6), a = 1:9, b = 9:1)

> DT
   x v y a b
1: b 1 1 1 9
2: b 1 3 2 8
3: b 1 6 3 7
4: a 2 1 4 6
5: a 2 3 5 5
6: a 1 6 6 4
7: c 1 1 7 3
8: c 2 3 8 2
9: c 2 6 9 1
```

I have a variable `sl <- c("a","b")` that selects columns to compute `rowSums`. If I try the code below

```
DT[, ab := rowSums(.SD[, ..sl])]
```

I am still able to get the desired output but given a warning message telling

> DT[, ab := rowSums(.SD[, ..sl])]
> Warning message:
> In `[.data.table`(.SD, , ..sl) :
> Both 'sl' and '..sl' exist in calling scope. Please remove the '..sl' variable in calling scope for clarity.

However, no warnings occur when running

```
DT[, ab := rowSums(.SD[, sl, with = FALSE])]
```

I am wondering how to fix the warning issue when using `.SD[, ..sl]`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It may be that the syntax to use is either specify the `.SDcols` and call the `.SD` or directly call the `..cols` from the original object.  According to `?data.table`

> x[, cols] is equivalent to x[, ..cols] and to x[, cols, with=FALSE] and to x[, .SD, .SDcols=cols]

if we check the source code of `data.table`, line 248 seems to be the one triggering the `warning`

[image]

as

```
DT[, exists(..sl, where = DT)]
#[1] TRUE
```

and

```
DT[, .SD[, exists(..sl)]]
#[1] TRUE

DT[, .SD[, exists(..sl, where = .SD)]]
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: By the way, does `.SD` refer to the same address in the memory  as `DT`, or another copy of `DT`? I am not clear how the mechanism of `.SD` is.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding the address shows different `pryr::address(DT)#[1] "0x7fb811b28200"` and `DT[, pryr::address(.SD)]#
[1] "0x7fb81094c000"`